# Wordpress: Some classes in bootstrap not working

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

Im having a problem in wordpress when i want to use classes in bootstrap like span, col-md, col-lg and also glyphicons. its not working

Here is my code:

Header

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

<!-- Le styles -->
<link href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url');?>" rel="stylesheet">

<title><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></title>

<?php wp_enqueue_script("jquery"); ?>
<?php wp_head(); ?>

<!-- Preventing from clicking back button in all browser -->
<script type="text/javascript">    
    window.history.forward();
    function noBack() { 
        window.history.forward(); 
    }
</script>   
</head>
```

Style(css)

```
/*
 Theme Name: CRM bootstrap
 Author: Mark
 Version: 1.0
*/

 @import url('bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css');
 @import url('bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css');  
 @import url('bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css');
 @import url('bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css'); 
 body { 
   margin-top: 60px;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need too add them to your `functions.php` file. Here is a demo of what that looks like,

```
function bluebreeze_script_enqueue(){

        //CSS
        wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/bootstrap.min.css', array(), '3.4.4', 'all');
        wp_enqueue_style('fontawesome', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css', array(), '4.4.0', 'all');
        wp_enqueue_style('customstyle', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/bluebreeze.css', array(), '1.0.0', 'all');

        //JS
        wp_enqueue_script('customjquery', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/jquery.min.js', array(), '2.1.4', true);
        wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/bootstrap.min.js', array(), '3.4.4', true);
        wp_enqueue_script('customjs', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/bluebreeze.js', array(), '1.0.0', true);

        //Angular Apps 
        if (is_page( array('mortgage-calculator', 'contact' ) )){
            wp_enqueue_script('angularjs', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/angular.min.js', array(), '1.4.1', true);
            wp_enqueue_script('d3', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/d3.min.js', array(), '10/22/2015', true);
            wp_enqueue_script('c3-js', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/c3.min.js', array(), '10/22/2015', true);
            wp_enqueue_script('c3-css', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/c3.min.css', array(), '10/22/2015', false);
            wp_enqueue_script('fcsaNumber', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/fcsaNumber.min.js', array(), '1.0.0', true);
            wp_enqueue_script('mortCalcApp', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/mortCalcApp.js', array(), '1.0.0', true);
        }

    }

    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'bluebreeze_script_enqueue');
```

Comment: what is 3.4.4 beside array in your style?

Comment: Its just the bootstrap version, [WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) covers this in detail, and how to set up your ``functions.php`` file.

Comment: is this the good practice for declaring stylesheets and scripts in wordpress? so my code is wrong? sorry for asking so many questions im just new in wordpress

Comment: yes it's wrong wordpress format, you *MUST* declare them in your ``functions.php`` file. WordPress has a specific structure you must follow, I suggest you look at the WordPress codex link I provided.

Comment: if i declare all of my stylesheets in functions.php glyphicons and other classes in bootstrap would work?

Comment: how to declare stylesheet in header after in functions.php?

Comment: they will all work, the boolean statement ``true`` ensures it will be in the head when the files parse.

Comment: i already declare in my functions.php but some of the classes are still not working including the glyphicons